# Analysis how many characters are in red, and how many characters are in blue

Tags: jquery

Currently, I have a HTML like the following.

```
<div style="color:red">AB<div style="color:blue">C</div>DEF</div>
```

Is there any way, I can iterate through the text, so that I can know I have 5 characters (`ABDEF`) in red, and 1 character (`C`) in blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, you can then filter it with style color.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ua9ndk/14/)

```
$('div').each(function(){
    debugger
    var color = $(this).prop('style').color;
    var len =     $(this).contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).text().length;
    console.log(color+ ' content length is :'+len);
})
```

Comment: I will get "ABCD" in first iteration, then "C" in second iteration. I would expect to have 3 iterations, with "AB", "C" and "D" respectively.

Comment: With above code, you got 2 iterations. console log will only give you 3 and 1. Try here http://jsfiddle.net/xurva9wt/4/

Comment: Hem... That's weird. Do you know why if I use `console.log(color+ ' content length is :'+$(this).contents().text());`, `ABCD` and `C` will be printed out?

Comment: Did you check jsfiddle demo. May be helpful if you post your html. or create a fiddle.

Comment: Note, your jsfiddle demo doesn't work with my revised example data. It still output 3 & 1. (5 & 1 is expected).

Answer (score 0):

One simple is way to move the inline style to css class  . Find their inner content length . Sample as below

```
<style>

A { color:red }

B { color:blue } </style> 

<html> <div class="A">AB<div class="B">C</div>D</div> </html>
```

> JS:

```
var totalLength=$('div.A').text().length  
var  blueLength=$('div.B').text().length 
var  redLength=totalLength-blueLength
```

Output: 3 in red and 1 in blue

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this!** It should finally solve your problem. - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/leo/a64Lta6u/12/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    reds = 0;
    blues = 0;

    $('div').each(function(){
        var css_style = $(this).attr('style');

        if(css_style.indexOf('color:red') > -1) {
            reds += $(this).text().length;
            if($(this).children().length > 0) {
                count = $(this).children().text().length;
                final_reds = reds - count;
            } else {
                final_reds = reds;
            }
        }

        if(css_style.indexOf('color:blue') > -1) {
            blues += $(this).text().length;
            if($(this).children().length > 0) {
                count = $(this).children().text().length;
                final_blues = blues - count;
            } else {
                final_blues = blues;
            }
        }

    });

    $('body').append('There are ' + final_reds + ' chars in red div(s) and '+ final_blues +' chars in blue div(s).');

});
```

Comment: It took me a while to finally understand your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `child div text` from `parent div text`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function findText($div) {
        var text = $div.text();
        $div.children().each(function () {
           text = text.replace($(this).text(), "")
        })
        return text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");//replace new line if want to
    }
    alert("in red" + findText($('div[style*="color:red"]')).length);
    alert("in blue" + findText($('div[style*="color:blue"]')).length);
});
```

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/a64Lta6u/13/